# Could you suggest a way to estimate an individual's risk-aversion

Tags: economics

Did you see real-world examples of a way to estimate an individual's risk-aversion roughly by making mini-surveys to individuals or making them play mini-games?
Do portfolio management companies do such things for their customers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can search for things called Risk Questionnaires, which some PM or financial advisors give to their customers. They vary greatly in quality/reliability.

Comment: "Could you suggest a way to estimate an individual's risk-aversion" - you might want to look at "certainty equivalent".